# Ambassador tracing integration with Istio's Jaeger

Tags: kubernetes, istio, zipkin, jaeger, ambassador

I have a working Ambassador and a working Istio and I use the default Jaeger tracer in Istio which works fine.

Now I would like to make Ambassador report trace data to Istio's Jaeger.

Ambassador documentation suggests that Jaeger is supported with the Zipkin driver, but gives example only for usage with Zipkin.

https://www.getambassador.io/user-guide/with-istio/#tracing-integration

So I checked the ports of jaeger-collector service, and picked the http: jaeger-collector-http  14268/TCP

```
kubectl describe svc jaeger-collector -n istio-system
```

And modified the TracingService shown in the Ambassador docs:

```
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: TracingService
metadata:
  name: tracing
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
spec:
  #service: "zipkin.istio-system:9411"
  service: "jaeger-collector.istio-system:14268"
  driver: zipkin
  ambassador_id: ambassador-{{ .Values.namespace }}
  config: {}
```

But I cannot see trace data from Ambassador in Jaeger.

Does anyone have any experience on this topic?

Comment: Have You tried to install istio with `--set values.global.tracer.zipkin.address=<jaeger-collector-service>.<jaeger-collector-namespace>:9411` as provided in [istio documentation](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/jaeger/#before-you-begin)?

Comment: Great! It works. And this time I used the original TracingService setting: service: "zipkin.istio-system:9411"

Comment: Happy to help, I made short answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer here is to install istio with `--set values.global.tracer.zipkin.address` as provided in [istio documentation](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/jaeger/#before-you-begin)

```
istioctl manifest apply --set values.global.tracer.zipkin.address=<jaeger-collector-service>.<jaeger-collector-namespace>:9411
```

---

**And**

---

Use the original TracingService `setting: service: "zipkin.istio-system:9411"` as Donato Szilagyi confirmed in comments.

```
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: TracingService
metadata:
  name: tracing
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
spec:
  service: "zipkin.istio-system:9411"
  driver: zipkin
  ambassador_id: ambassador-{{ .Values.namespace }}
  config: {}
```

> Great! It works. And this time I used the original TracingService setting: service: "zipkin.istio-system:9411" – Donato Szilagy